Spyder dataframe view: disable background color as default
When viewing dataframes or NumPy arrays in Spyder the checkbox 'Background Color' is selected pr. default. I don't like this, so I always manually uncheck it, but this becomes tedious to do every single time I view a dataframe. Can I disable this pr. default?
I'm using Python 3.12.4, Spyder 5.5.1 on Windows 11.
